# Linking two models in an App together in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I was wondering if besides having inlines in a model to actually create a link to the related model

```
class A():
   var1 = 
   var2 =

class B():
   var1 = models.ManyToManyField(A)
   var2 =
   var3=
```

admin.py:

```
class BInline(admin.TabularInline):
  model = B
  def

class AAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = BInline
```

and in admin they are related with a through inline; however I actually want to either link to model B within model A and vice versa because right now the only thing I can do is add new B's to A or vice versa by name but I cannot edit the other variables within B from A.

I want to ease the transition of managing the models in the admin page by allowing direct access to the B from A.

I tried creating an admin link, but it says unknown field (admin_link) specified for BInline

```
def admin_link(self, instance):
    url = reverse('admin:%s_%s_change' % (instance._meta.app_label, instance._meta.module_name), args=[instance.id])
    return mark_safe(u'<a href="{u}">Edit</a>'.format(u=url))
    fields = ('choice_text','votes','admin_link')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about create a C class
something like:

```
class C(A, B):
    var1 = 
    var2 = ....
```

and in the admin page u may access all fields from both models

Comment: Would that be pertinent to Django though? I'm using python.

Comment: yes, i've done stuff like that. 
do not forget that : class a & b should inherit from model.models

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider that option.